# searching through a array of string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, if-statement, for-loop

so i have this set of strings which are stored in an array i want to search the array so when the string is found it should say `found` and when its not found it should say `invalid`
this is what i have so far

```
cout << "Enter a Name to Search" <<endl;
cin >>userInput;

for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
   if (first_name[i]==userInput)
    {
        cout <<"Found"<<endl;
    }else{
          cout << "InValid"<<endl;
            break;
         }  
}
```

so every time i run this i am always redirected to The else Statement is there anyway for me to fix this

Comment: Please edit your question to provide [mcve]

Comment: You can walk this code on paper (or in your head) and see what happens if `userInput` is the second entry in the `first_name` array.

Comment: Provide minimal code to reproduce your problem. How `size` is declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a more elegant solution would use a boolean flag, like:

```
cout << "Enter a Name to Search" <<endl;
cin >>userInput;
bool found = false;

for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
  if (first_name[i]==userInput)
  {
     found = true;
     break;
  }
}

cout << (found?"found":"invalid") << endl;
```

Comment: i guess you are correct but may you explain what is that question mark here does `cout << (found?"found":"invalid") << endl;`

Comment: thats a C/C++ ternary operator (see  http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html ) that I used for avoiding an `if` statement.

Comment: okay i get it its kinda shortcut way of writing `if then else` statement

Comment: yes, it increases the readability in most cases. So, was that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Use containers like `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` for fast searching.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> first_name;
    first_name.insert("Joe");
    first_name.insert("Anderson");
    //....

    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::unordered_set<std::string>::iterator searchResult = first_name.find(input); // Search for the string. If nothing is found end iterator will be returned
    if(searchResult != first_name.end())
        std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Not found!" << std::endl;
}
```

Programm output when "Joe" was typed:

```
Found!
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

For your example everything is okey, if `userInput` is `std::string`, `first_name` is array of `std::string` and variable `size` store array size.

Comment: it looks kinda complex for me

Comment: @f2355116 I can add fix for arrays, if you edit your question and add the minimal code to reproduce problem. How `size` is declared?

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking from the else part. So for instance if the array is size of 10, and if you give userinput as string present in 5th array element, your code will break at the first iteration of the for loop. Try the below code. If match found, It will print "found", or if the the userinput not there in the array it will print invalid. Hope it helps. Initialize the "first_name" with your array element and change the size.

```
string userInput;
string first_name[10];
int i=0;
int size = 10;

first_name[0] = "Hi";
first_name[1] = "Hii";
first_name[2] = "Hiii";
cout << "Enter a Name to Search" <<endl;
cin >> userInput;

for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    if (first_name[i] == userInput)
    {
        cout <<"Found"<< endl;
        break;
    }
}
if(i == size)
    cout << "Invalid" << endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

so i was able to find a solution this is what i did

```
    string result =""; //set a string named result 
    cout << "Enter a Name to Search" <<endl;
    cin >>userInput;

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
       if (!(first_name[i]==userInput))
        {
           result = "Found";
            break;
        }else{
              result ="InValid";

             }  
    }
     cout <<result<<endl;  //outside of for loop
```

Comment: looks like your break is in the wrong block. It should break whenever you find the string